# Web3 Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: web3js, contract-development, truffle, metamask

I'm new to dapp and trying to follow iwaldman to build an ipfs-image-dapp. Here is the repo: https://github.com/iwaldman/ipfs-image-dapp.

But running yarn start gives the error Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined.
I have tried the method given by the net such as

```
    if (typeof contract.currentProvider.sendAsync !== "function") {
       contract.currentProvider.sendAsync = function() {
         return contract.currentProvider.send.apply(
            contract.currentProvider,
            arguments
    );
  };
}
```

But it gives another error that Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window'.

I must have done something wrong. I'm using the latest metamask and ganache v2.0.1. I have turned off metamask's privacy mode. Could anyone give me some advice? Thank you.

Please forgive my poor English.

Comment: @SanjaySB: The error implies that `contract.currentProvider` does not have a property (variable or function) named `send`, which implies that your suggestion is incorrect.

Comment: opps. ok. I have removed the suggestion.

Comment: Should I provide more information? I'm not sure what kind of information is helpful.